# How do you get variable from one package to another

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have `Package A`, my main package, and `Package B` that I'm using as a library. Both of these compile to make one `.swf`

The `flashvars` are only accessible in the first package, but I need them to be in the second package.

So I put the variable that I needed in a static class inside of `Package A`. However I can't access or import this class into `Package B` for some reason.

How can I get this variable over to `Package B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share code it must be in a library SWC.

It sounds like your code in package A is not a library. Put the static class in a library SWC (package B?). Then in your main SWF, populate the static var at startup.

Comment: This looks Promising. I'll try it. By the way, you've answered, like, three of my questions in a row, you know that, right?